# MLFlow: How to debug database connection

Tags: mysql, docker, mlflow

I created a mlflow docker image, but I can't connect mysql database on another docker image. You can see a snippet of the script to start mlflow container.

```
...
DB_BACKEND="mysql+pymysql://${MLFLOW_USER}:${MLFLOW_PASS}@$IP:${MYSQL_PORT1}/mlflow"
MLFLOW_CMD="mlflow server --backend-store-uri ${DB_BACKEND} --artifacts-destination /mlartifacts --serve-artifacts -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5000"

docker run --rm \
  --name mlflow-server \
  -p 5000:5000 \
  --volume ${DIR_SERVER}/artifacts:/mlartifacts \
  -d mlflow-ubuntu-22.04:22110701 \
  ${MLFLOW_CMD}
```

When I check the logs I see these messages.

```
$ docker logs mlflow-server
2022/11/08 15:33:34 WARNING mlflow.store.db.utils: SQLAlchemy engine could not be created. The following exception is caught.
(pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.2' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
Operation will be retried in 0.1 seconds
```

I can connect mysql from mlflow docker image with my user/password and I have permission to create a table without problems.

```
$ docker exec -it mlflow-server bash
root@b68c447b5ce9:/# mysql -u mlflow -p -h 172.17.0.2 mlflow
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2413
Server version: 8.0.31 MySQL Community Server - GPL
Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> CREATE TABLE test(id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.91 sec)

mysql> show tables;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_mlflow |
+------------------+
| test             |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> drop table test;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.41 sec)

mysql>
```

How do I fix the connection with Mysql server? How do I debug the mlflow connection?

Best regards,